# How can you download all the data from a Facebook Group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have a private group in Facebook for a group of classmates. I know with the [tools](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/) Facebook provides you are able to download your own data. However, I want to download all the status updates, images, docs, etc... from a Facebook group. Is this possible?

Comment: This might be worthwhile - http://estebandamiani.com/downloading-facebook-group-data/

Comment: Any way to know if this is legit? It looks very interesting, I just don't want to give away my Facebook data to just anybody.

Answer (score 2):

If DIY effort and some Ruby is ok, you might enjoy article [How We Used Facebook to Power Our Investigation Into Patient Harm](http://www.propublica.org/article/how-we-used-facebook-to-power-our-investigation-into-patient-harm) and scroll down to section "Whenever Possible, Structure Social Data", it has general description and then more detailed sub-section "How To Download Your Facebook Group Data"

Answer (score 1):

The short of it is that no, Facebook does not provide a way for you to download a dump of a group's data. The only way to do it would be to write your own custom spider that crawled, parsed, and downloaded data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a “pay for” service to do this.

http://www.personalgroupware.com/Facebook.htm

I think it’s min $150 though.

(You might want to club together with other group members to afford it.)

Comment: There's no need to pay for it, facebook gives it out for free.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know for particular group but we can download our whole data on Facebook.

Go to *Settings→General*, there you will see the link *Download a copy of your Facebook data* at the bottom.

Just click on the *Link→Start→My archive*→enter your Facebook password→*Submit*. In the confirmation message, click on *Start my archive*.

They will send you all archived data on your email, just check your inbox & open the mail ,in it they have provided the link to download data, click on link & get your data.

Comment: The OP specifically stated that he already knows about this feature. I do not believe this is an answer to the question.

Comment: "Download a copy of your Facebook Data" does NOT include the contents of your groups, but only a list of groups you belong to. Your group data is locked into Facebook.